# How can I show my image in CodeIgniter base_url

Tags: php, css, image, codeigniter

How can I show my image in this situation?

Here is my code:

```
<div class="clinic-logo" style="background-image: url( <?= base_url() ?>asset/dist/css/img/mylogo.gif )"></div>
```

When I saw it in inspect element it gives me this:

```
background-image: url( http://localhost/clinic/asset/dist/css/img/mylogo.gif );
```

Why does it say 'could not load image'?

Comment: you need `background-image: url("http://localhost/clinic/asset/dist/css/img/mylogo.gif");` You forget the double quotes

Comment: make sure the image is available on that specified path, also you must define the height and width of the div to make the image display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
<div class="clinic-logo" style="background-image: url('<?php echo base_url();?>asset/dist/css/img/mylogo.gif')"></div>
```

Don't forget to load `url` helper in `application/config/autoload.php`.

Comment: After an hour of trying I couldn't make base_url() work, I got "function undefined", even after including "autoload.php", so I suppose this hack doesn't work anymore or with my CI version. In that case you just can use $base_url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; and voila, problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

should do the trick

```
<div class="clinic-logo" style="background-image: url("<?php echo base_url('asset/dist/css/img/mylogo.gif');?>")"></div>
```

anything passed into base_url() will be appended

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class"container">
<img src="<? = base_url('Your image path')?>">
</div>
```